# selecting workstation delay time from one of three tables based on process type in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I have a production line with four work stations (ws1, ws2, ws3, ws4).  There are three different process approaches (Push, Pull3, Pull1).  Depending on the process approach the delay time for each workstation may differ during each period of operation (associated with the "ws1timeParameter" for example).  Right now I have three tables, (Push, Pull3, Pull1).  Each table has columns containing workstation ws1, ws2, ws3 and ws4 delay times. The following works fine when I'm fixed to one process approach (in this example, the push process)

```
 selectFrom(push)
.where(push.period.eq(ws1timeParameter))
.uniqueResult(push.ws1, double.class)
```

How can I insert a conditional in the Delay so that it applies the table associated with the process type selected.  (I have a combo box tied to a variable to hold the process type).

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Use a conditional statement within the delay block's duration code line such as `myType == push ? selectFrom(push)... : selectFrom(pull)...`
   These are called conditional statements, and you can have nested conditions as well, check Google for more info (it is a Java feature)
2. Create a function and write out standard `if else` statements. The function takes your delay type (push1, pull...) as an argument as well as all other information to pull the right dbase value. And it returns the process time as a double. Call the function from the Delay's duration code box (instead of your SQL code)

cheers

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Ben -- we're up and running.

Comment: Lovely. Please flag the answer as "Useful" (the up-arrow left to it) so others can find it easier in the future as well ;-)